# flask db init not executing properly for flask migrate

Tags: python, flask

```
Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]
```

'''

```
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did 
not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and 
a   "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the 
current directory
```

'''

I am not using the single app method, i am using flask as a module(__**init**.py)  and i have tried running

```
set FLASK_APP = flask_app #("directory which the init.py stays in")
```

i also tried

```
set FlASK_APP =  run.py
```

and when i run

```
flask db init
```

it still gives me same error

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found out the problem was caused by my spacing when setting flask_app in the terminal (cmd)

I did this:

```
set FLASK_APP = flask_app
```

instead of:

```
set FLASK_APP=flask_app
```

I remembered i encountered this problem working with flask for the first ion windows so i had to fix it that way before i could perform flask run command.

Comment: Thanks, for posting your solution. I had been scratching my head on this all day.